# Почему в первом коде не нужен нулевой символ?

Tags: c++

У нас есть функция которая принимает две строки и производит слияние

```
void strcat(char *to, const char *from)
{
    while (*to) to++;
    while (*to++ = *from++);
}
```

Почему здесь не требуется добавить нулевой символ в отличие например от такого кода

```
void strcat(char *to, const char *from)
{
    while (*to != '\0') {
        to++;
    }

    while (*from != '\0') {
        *to = *from;
        from++;
        to++;
    }
    *to = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `while ((*to++ = *from++));` должно быть в первом примере.

Comment: @0andriy А чем отличается это выражение от того что в примере в техническом плане?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нулевой символ здесь добавляется автоматом.

Выражение

```
*to++ = *from++
```

выполняет присвоение, после чего возвращает новое значение *to. То есть, сначала ноль скопируется из *from в *to, а уж потом он будет проанализирован в while, который прекратится.